# How to set spring active profiles with maven profiles

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-profiles

I have an application with maven as a build tool.

I am using maven profiles to set up different properties from different profiles.

What i would like to do is that all active profiles in maven will be ported to spring active profiles as well so i can reference them in bean signature (`@profile`). but i am not sure how to do it.

for example: consider the following maven setup

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <properties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>    
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

assuming i run maven with out specifying any other profiles i would like for spring to have `profile1` and  `development` as active profiles.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll have to filter a resources of your application, for instance a property file, that holds the information of which profile to activate in spring.

For instance

```
spring.profile = ${mySpringProfile}
```

And for each profile, define a value for this variable (`mySpringProfile`).

During the build, this will be filtered accordingly to the value defined in the currently active profile.

Then during the bootstrap of your application you'll select the appropriated profile according to this file (can't help you more as you didn't gave us more information, but this is quite easy.

**Note**: I can't find a way to get the currently active profile in maven (something like project.profiles.active that holds your -P values), that's why you'll have to set a new variable for each profile.

**Note 2**: if you are running a web application, instead of using this intermediate file, filter this value in your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>${mySpringProfile}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Note 3**: This is actually a bad practice, and you should set the profile at runtime with a system property

Comment: why is this bad practice? what i want to do is according to the maven profile to enable certain beans that compliment the configurations with different environments. i am not using a web application. this is a simple executable jar. with the resource solution i will need to first raise my context, then set active profiles and then refresh that might drop some of the beans created and create others. i would like the correct beans to be loaded with out the switch

Comment: @Gleeb Well, in general, this is better (because more flexible) to provide a unique release that will behave differently according to the run time configuration instead of generating 3 different binaries. But still it depends on your business. It is up to you :p

Comment: any example to do it in a java base config? (non web.xml)

Comment: Regarding your first note, the command is  >mvn help:active-profiles

Answer (score 49):

There is a more elegant way to switch between 2 maven+spring profiles simultaneously.

**First**, add profiles to POM (pay attention - maven+spring profile is activated by single system variable):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>postgres</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>postgres</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>h2</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>h2</value>
            </property>
        </activation>           
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.191</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**Second**, set default profile for spring (for maven it is already set in POM). For web application, I inserted following lines to `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
   <param-value>postgres</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Third**, add profile-dependent beans to your config. In my case (XML config), it is:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties" ref="hibProps"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>my.test.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
...
<beans profile="postgres">
    <bean name="mainDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/webchat" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres" />
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="h2">
    <bean name="mainDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:file:./newsdb;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:init.sql';TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Now it is possible to:

- Run my web-app on Postgres DB with `mvn jetty:run` or `mvn jetty:run -Dspring.profiles.active=postgres` commands
- Run my web-app on H2 DB with `mvn clean jetty:run -Dspring.profiles.active=h2`

Comment: This is so much better for my use case. Thank you for this. Note that if the Maven profile is explicitly set along side `spring.profiles.active` then it will take precedence

Answer (score 34):

The first thing you need is two properties files for keeping your configurations. The names of the files should match with the pattern application-{custom_suffix}.properties. Create them in the src/main/resources directory of your Maven project, next to the main application.properties file, which you’re going to use later to activate one of the others and to hold values shared by both profiles.

Then it’s time to modify your pom.xml. You need to define a custom property in each of your Maven profiles and set their values to match with suffixes of corresponding properties files that you want to load with a particular profile. The following sample also marks the first profile to run by default, but it’s not mandatory.

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
        <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <properties>
        <activatedProperties>release</activatedProperties>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Next, in the build section of the same file, configure filtering for the Resources Plugin. That will allow you to insert properties defined in the previous step into any file in the resources directory, which is the subsequent step.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    …
</build>
```

Finally, add the following line to the application.properties.

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

When the build is run, the Resources Plugin will replace the placeholder with the value of the property defined in the active Maven profile. After starting  your application, the Spring framework will load the appropriate configuration file based on the name of the active Spring profile, which is described by the value of the spring.profiles.active property. Note that Spring Boot 1.3 replaced the default Resources Plugin syntax for filtered values and uses `@activatedProperties@` instead of `${activatedProperties}` notation.

It worked to perfection. Hope this can help you.

Comment: I just want to add that you can also select the profile when generating the war : mvn package -P release   (whith release the id of your maven profile defined in the POM)

Comment: does this work only in Spring boot, or Spring Framework in general? I mean the `spring.profiles.active` in the `application.properties` part? Would you please guide me to the documentation part that discusses this?

Answer (score 9):

For a Spring Boot application, one can add a property in the Maven profile in `pom.xml` and then reference that property in `application.properties`.

Add Maven profiles to `pom.xml` with, for example, a property called `spring.profile.from.maven`:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>postgres</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <spring.profile.from.maven>postgres</spring.profile.from.maven>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>noDb</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profile.from.maven>noDb</spring.profile.from.maven>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Reference the Maven property in `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.include=@spring.profile.from.maven@
```

With this setup, running maven with the `postgres` Maven profile or with no profile adds the `postgres` Spring profile to the list of Spring's active profiles, while running maven with the `noDb` Maven profile adds the `noDb` Spring profile to the list of Spring's active profiles.

Answer (score 3):

Add placeholder `${activeProfile}` in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
  <param-value>${activeProfile}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Set properties in pom.xml for each profile:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>profile1</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <activeProfile>profile1</activeProfile>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>profile2</id>
    <properties>
      <activeProfile>profile2</activeProfile>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Add `maven-war-plugin` and set `<filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>` to replace the placeholder when running `mvn package -Pprofile1` or `mvn package -Pprofile2`:

```
<build>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently building a small webapp that (due to reasons beyond my control) has to be capable of running on an old server/container that only supports Servlet 2.5 and Java 6. There is also a requirement for the webapp configuration to be completely self-contained, so even system variables and/or JVM parameters cannot be used. The administrator just wants a .war file for each environment that can be dropped into the container for deployment.

I'm using Spring 4.x in my webapp. This is how I configured my application such that the active Maven profile is used to set the active Spring 4.x profile.

---

**pom.xml file changes**

I added the following bits to my POM file. My POM is using model version 4.0.0 and I'm running Maven 3.1.x when I do my builds.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

...

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <!-- Default to dev so we avoid any accidents with prod! :) -->
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- This can be a single value, or a comma-separated list -->
            <spring.profiles.to.activate>dev</spring.profiles.to.activate>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>uat</id>
        <properties>
            <!-- This can be a single value, or a comma-separated list -->
            <spring.profiles.to.activate>uat</spring.profiles.to.activate>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <!-- This can be a single value, or a comma-separated list -->
            <spring.profiles.to.activate>prod</spring.profiles.to.activate>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

...

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <webResource>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/web.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </webResource>
                </webResources>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

**web.xml file changes**

```
<!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Setup for root Spring context
-->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-core-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<!--
Jim Tough - 2016-11-30
Per Spring Framework guide: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-environment

...profiles may also be activated declaratively through the spring.profiles.active 
property which may be specified through system environment variables, JVM system 
properties, servlet context parameters in web.xml, or even as an entry in JNDI.
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>${spring.profiles.to.activate}</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
```

---

Now I can create Java-based configuration classes like the one below that will only be used when a particular Spring profile is active.

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"dev","default"})
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class PersistenceContext {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

spring boot plugin itself can help:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>postgres</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <jmxPort>9001</jmxPort>
              <environmentVariables>
                <SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE>postgres</SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE>
              </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>h2</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <jmxPort>9002</jmxPort>
              <environmentVariables>
                <SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE>h2</SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE>
              </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the spring boot application, there are several ways to set profiles (dev, uat, prod, etc.)

For exmaple : You can add this in your property file:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Programmatically:

```
SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles("dev");
```

To specify what profiles are active, use this line

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
```

In a Unix environment

```
export spring_profiles_active=dev
```

Running the jar file with the dev profile.

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev JARNAME.jar
```

here `JARNAME.jar` means your application's jar