# How to keep Intellij IDEA from adding scope=provided to Tomcat dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA as IDE on a spring boot multi-module maven project.

But it keeps editing each project's `.iml` file and adds `scope="PROVIDED"` to all Tomcat dependencies. So, in order to run the project, I have to edit out all `scope="PROVIDED"` from these lines. It's not difficult or too time consuming, just very annoying.

Is there a way prevent this from happening? I've considered creating a small script, but I really don't want to pollute the workspace with some home-brewed solution.

Comment: Could you show us your POM? Or at least these aspects of it: (a) the `<packaging>` tag; (b) the 'Tomcat dependencies" to which you refer and (c) any Spring dependencies.

Comment: I think I got it... there was a `<scope>provided</scope>` entry for the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` artifact. I'm running tests now to check that removing the scope declaration won't affect too much. Thanks!

Comment: I used the approach described in the answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299263/make-a-maven-dependency-provided-based-on-active-spring-profile