# Skip maven dependencies based on a flag

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am trying to set up a Parent pom for my services to easily manage dependencies. I have my parent pom like this,

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-common-parent-bom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>myapp-common-parent-bom</name>

    <properties>
        <springboot.version>2.7.12</springboot.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version> 
        <swagger.version>1.6.3</swagger.version>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And, I am using this as the parent in other services. Sample here,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-common-parent-bom</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>my-service</name>
</project>
```

Now, I would like to control the dependencies that I need to install in my service using a flag. Something like this `<useLombok>true</useLombok>`. How can I do this?

I tried this in the parent pom, but it din't work.

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>!${useLombok}</optional>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

So, I am looking for help how I can achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a maven dependency provided based on active spring profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299263/make-a-maven-dependency-provided-based-on-active-spring-profile)

Comment: if the packaging is pom, almost all the time you don't want to specify dependencies like this. Instead use `dependencyManagement` and let the projects using this parent decide if they want the dependency. This might also solve your original question.

Comment: Yeah, I know I could use dependencyManagement. I tried that first and it works well. But wanted to try if there any other solutions to it.