# Configure active profile in SpringBoot via Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to set an active profile in Spring Boot application using Maven 3.
In my pom.xml I set **default active profile** and property **spring.profiles.active**  to **development**:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>development</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

but every time I run my application, I receive the following message in logs:

```
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

and the SpringBoot profile is set to default (reads application.properties instead application-development.properties)
What else should I do to have my SpringBoot active profile set using Maven profile?
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420745/how-to-set-spring-active-profiles-with-maven-profiles

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The Maven profile and the Spring profile are two completely different things. Your pom.xml defines `spring.profiles.active` variable which is available in the build process, but not at runtime. That is why only the default profile is activated.

**How to bind Maven profile with Spring?**

You need to pass the build variable to your application so that it is available when it is started.

1. Define a placeholder in your `application.properties`:

   ```
   spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
   ```

   The `@spring.profiles.active@` variable must match the declared property from the Maven profile.
2. Enable resource filtering in you pom.xml:

   ```
   <build>
       <resources>
           <resource>
               <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
           </resource>
       </resources>
       …
   </build>
   ```

   When the build is executed, all files in the `src/main/resources` directory will be processed by Maven and the placeholder in your `application.properties` will be replaced with the variable you defined in your Maven profile.

For more details you can [go to my post](http://dolszewski.com/spring/spring-boot-properties-per-maven-profile/) where I described this use case.

Comment: Is there a way to enable profile for unit tests via maven command? Maybe you have an idea for [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47833555/3493036)

Comment: I just want to add that you can set the active profile with the commamd mvn package -P myProfile where my profile is defined in the POM

Comment: If you are running from jar use `java -Dspring.profiles.active=<profile-name> your-application.jar `

Answer (score 59):

Or rather easily:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles={profile_name}
```

Comment: Although this does not answer the question "how to set springboot active profile via maven", but it gives me answer to "how to set springboot:run active profile".

Comment: with Spring2.x, spring.profiles.active setting didnt work, either directly or via jvmArguments. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 37):

There are multiple ways to set profiles for your springboot application.

1. You can add this in your property file:

   ```
   spring.profiles.active=dev
   ```
2. Programmatic way:

   ```
   SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles("dev");
   ```
3. Tests make it very easy to specify what profiles are active

   ```
   @ActiveProfiles("dev")
   ```
4. In a Unix environment

   ```
   export spring_profiles_active=dev
   ```
5. JVM System Parameter

   ```
   -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
   ```

**Example: Running a springboot jar file with profile.**

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev application.jar
```

Comment: >You can add this in your property file:

In which properties file? as profile is needed to pickup respective application.xxx.properties

Comment: starting from Spring 2.4 spring.profiles.active has been changed to spring.config.active.on-profile=dev

Answer (score 18):

You can run using the following command. Here I want to run using spring profile `local`:

`spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=local"`

Comment: Best answer! Worked for me using maven 3.5.2 + java 1.8 + spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE on mac os 10.13.3

Comment: Where do i add it?

Answer (score 16):

In development, activating a Spring Boot profile when a specific Maven profile is activate is straight. You should use [the `profiles` property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#profiles) of the [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) in the Maven profile such as :

```
<project>
    <...>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <profiles>
                                <profile>development</profile>
                            </profiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    <profiles>
    </...>
</project>
```

You can run the following command to use both the Spring Boot and the Maven `development` profile :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Pdevelopment
```

---

If you want to be able to map any Spring Boot profiles to a Maven profile with the same profile name, you could define a single Maven profile and enabling that as the presence of a Maven property is detected. This property would be the single thing that you need to specify as you run the `mvn` command.
The profile would look like :

```
    <profile>
        <id>spring-profile-active</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>my.active.spring.profiles</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <profiles>
                            <profile>${my.active.spring.profiles}</profile>
                        </profiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

And you can run the following command to use both the Spring Boot and the Maven `development` profile :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dmy.active.spring.profiles=development
```

or :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dmy.active.spring.profiles=integration
```

or :

```
 mvn spring-boot:run -Dmy.active.spring.profiles=production
```

And so for...

This kind of configuration makes sense as in the generic Maven profile you rely on the `my.active.spring.profiles` property that is passed to perform some tasks or value some things.
For example I use this way to configure a generic Maven profile that packages the application and build a docker image specific to the environment selected.

Answer (score 9):

You should use the **Spring Boot Maven Plugin**:

```
<project>  
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <configuration>
          <profiles>
            <profile>foo</profile>
            <profile>bar</profile>
          </profiles>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: easier, faster, cleaner, no head bumping whatsoever. +1 for me

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to clarify the excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42391322/13134499 from Daniel Olszewski if you want to use it just for tests.

**How to bind Maven profile with Spring for *tests*?**

1. As you did, define the variable in `pom.xml`

```
...
<properties>
  <spring.profiles.active>development</spring.profiles.active>
</properties>
```

2. Define a placeholder in your `application-test.properties` in `src/test/resources`:

```
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
```

3. Enable resource filtering in you `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
  ...
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
  <testResources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to run an automation test in different environments.
So I add this to command maven command:

```
spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=productionEnv1"
```

Here is the link where I found the solution: [1]https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1095

Comment: `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun:jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=prod"` --> When I run this, I still get `No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default`

Answer (score 1):

**file structure:**

/src/main/resources

=>

application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active:@spring.profiles.active@'
```

application-dev.properties

application-prod.properties

**IDE-Eclipse:**

```
Right click on the project=>Run As=>Run Configuration=>Arguments=>VM Arguments:-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

**CMD:**

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Answer (score -3):

I added this in the first line

```
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
server.port=9898
```