# Springboot profiles for externally deployed war

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a springboot application that is deployed to an external tomcat server, everything works in my local with local DB. Now, i have to promote the code to higher environments where the DB configurations are different. I read a lot about profiles with `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` etc.., but how will the spring project know which server it is in when its an external tomcat and not using 
`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: JNDI is also supported, check the docs

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev environmental variable using CATALINA_OPTS

Comment: Assuming i can't use that either, what else can i use ? I'm using Jenkins to build the code & promote. I think there is config in jenkins that knows which server it is ? do you anything like that to configure. delete applications.properties and replace with application-dev.properties

Comment: you could use maven (or gradle) profiles then, but it is a different issue than what you asked

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the ways to externalized properties and setting profiles [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should link spring boot profile with maven one like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390860/configure-active-profile-in-springboot-via-maven) .

Thus you can build your jar package specifying the spring boot wanted profile  :

```
mvn clean install -P Prod
```