# How to specify Spring boot profile when running tests in IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

With IntelliJ, I can specify a Spring boot profile to run when starting a service
[image]

However, if I run `mvn clean install`, then the tests are run with the default profile, which causes them to fail.  How can I tell mvn to run the tests with a specific Spring Boot profile?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390860/configure-active-profile-in-springboot-via-maven

Comment: @BarbetNL using Maven profiles is the wrong way.

Comment: You have to define the profiles in your tests or even better use the appropriate `application.properteis` in `src/test/resources` for all tests or define them at the appropriate tests (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.1/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles)

Comment: There are some other suggestions in that link I posted. There are many ways to do this. Peter's question is how to do it in command-line: 
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active={profile_name}

Answer (score 2):

Create/define a properties file and put it within your `src/test/resources` folder.

Use class level annotation `@ActiveProfiles` and specify your property file name like this `@ActiveProfiles("myProperties")`

Hope this helps!