# Profile activation in appengine:deploy

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I'm trying to activate profiles of an AppEngine application using the maven command like the following :

```
mvn appengine:deploy -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

But it is ignored.

Is it possible to activate profiles using maven ?

Comment: Did you add profiles to POM?can you show?

Comment: @user7294900 I'm handling spring profiles not maven profiles, so I have no profiles in the POM. But even if I use maven profiles I will end up with the same problem ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420745/how-to-set-spring-active-profiles-with-maven-profiles

Comment: I've already tried this. The problem is the **mvn appengine:deploy** it seems that the deployed version in GCP ignore every option specified in the maven command

Comment: I solved the issue using **appengine-web.xml** file

Comment: You can answer your own question

Comment: I posted the answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I succeeded by linking Maven Profiles to Spring Profiles. In the following I explain how I did :

## 1 - Create Maven Profiles:

In **pom.xml** I identified my maven profiles, and will link them later to spring profiles by storing them in "spring.profiles.to.activate" property :

```
<!-- PROFILES -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.to.active>dev</spring.profiles.to.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>uat</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.to.active>uat</spring.profiles.to.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.to.active>prod</spring.profiles.to.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

## 2 - Activate Maven filtering :

I activated filtering in folder ${basedir}/src/main/webapp, by adding maven-war-plugin  to build. 
This will allow us to resolve placeholders ${...} (In this particular case ${spring.profiles.to.activate}) in the mentioned folder.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resources>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
            </resources>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

## 3- Activate profile Spring

In **appengine-web.xml** declare the system property : "spring.profiles.active" as being the maven property ${spring.profiles.to.activate}

```
<appengine-web-app
    xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="spring.profiles.active" value="${spring.profiles.to.active}" />
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

## 4 - Deploy to Appengine

```
# Dev
mvn appengine:deploy -Pdev
# UAT
mvn appengine:deploy -Puat
#PROD
mvn appengine:deploy -Pprod
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#dev profile, try adding space between -P and dev
mvn appengine:deploy  -P dev   
#uat profile, try adding space between -P and uat
mvn appengine:deploy  -P qa
#prod profile, try adding space between -P and prod
mvn appengine:deploy  -P prd
```