# How to Disable Spring Rest Docs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

**PROBLEM** I use [Spring Rest Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/) in my project. It is useful at development stage, but i don't want it to be available for ordinary users and search engines in production.

**RESEARCH** I see no robot meta tags with content like "nocache" & "noindex". What is expected actually is maybe a spring application.property field like `spring.rest-docs.enabled=false`. So that I can configure it in production spring profile.

**QUESTION** How to disable rest docs for some spring profiles.

Comment: `@Profile` that bean.

Comment: Spring REST Docs should only be used in your application's tests. When you say you "don't want it to be available", what is it, precisely, that you don't want to be available? Perhaps some HTML-based documentation that Asciidoctor has produced using the snippets that Spring REST Docs has generated?

Comment: Yupp. It is copied by Maven to a /resources/static/docs folder.

Answer (score 1):

There were three ways to do it:

- (**failed**) block a test with test-class annotations (couldn't setup it to work): `@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active", values = {"prod"})` or `@EnabledIf("${spring.restdocs.enabled}")`
- (**failed**) configure maven-resources-plugin to work with maven-profiles and spring profiles (looked too cumbersome): https://stackoverflow.com/a/45817386/1112963
- (**worked**) disable `/resources/static` folder access in `application-prod.properties` with `spring.resources.add-mappings=false`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this property to your `application.properties`

```
spring.test.restdocs.failOnUndocumentedFields=false
spring.test.restdocs.failOnUndocumentedParams=false
```

https://scacap.github.io/spring-auto-restdocs/#_configuration

> Configuration available during MockMvc setup:
>
> failOnUndocumentedParams - if build should fail on at least one undocumented parameter
> failOnUndocumentedFields - if build should fail on at least one undocumented field