# Spring Boot Not Resolving Properties Variable When Using spring-boot:run

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

This was working for me and I'm not sure what changed.. I have my spring boot profile configured to be set based on a maven profile. The basics:

application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=@environment@
```

pom.xml:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <environment>development</environment>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <environment>production</environment>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

When I run `mvn clean package -Pdevelopment` I see the line `The following profiles are active: development`.

Yet when I run `mvn spring-boot:run -Pdevelopment` I see the line `The following profiles are active: @environment@`.

Using the `spring-boot:run` command seems to not be able to resolve application property variables based on maven environment variables. Anyone know why? I tried adjusting the spring starter version without success.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.overriding-command-line), you could tune the profiles to enable when running the application as follows:

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=development
```

If not, try to comment your "spring.profiles.active" property in application.properties, that should work!

See also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420745/how-to-set-spring-active-profiles-with-maven-profiles#answer-36200076).

Comment: Thanks, this does properly set the spring profile but then I lose the maven profile functionality by bypassing it. I did dig a little longer into those docs and found the flag that was overriding the default property expansion behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this tip](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.properties-and-configuration.expand-properties.maven) in the docs, I added a configuration to my `spring-boot-maven-plugin` which broke this functionality:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <addResources>true</addResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Removing the addResources configuration restores the property expansion behavior.