# Activate Maven Profile from Spring Profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

Suppose I have some Maven profiles and some Spring profiles. I would like to manage all my profiles in an application-(spring-profile).yaml. Is it possible to activate a Maven Profile from a Spring Profile? I read about activating Spring profiles from Maven, but I have not found anything about activating Maven profiles from Spring.

### Example

#### pom.xml

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                ... (in my case some Postman Collections)
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

#### manifest-dev.yaml

```
spring:
   profiles:
      active: integration-tests, other-spring-profile
```

The Maven profile `integration-tests` is activated as a Spring profile in the example. I am looking for a preferably declarative way to activate Maven profiles in the application.yaml files

Comment: You cannot do that. The other way around would work but you cannot activate a maven profile from spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

In `application.properties` set

```
spring.profile = ${yourActiveSpringProfile}
```

You can see something around at [How to set spring active profiles with maven profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420745/how-to-set-spring-active-profiles-with-maven-profiles)