# How to activate Maven profiles with Spring pr

Tags: java, spring, maven

Suppose I have two Spring profiles - A and B - and two Maven profiles - similarly A and B. Is there a solution to activate Maven A profile when the Spring application is launched with A profile? In other words, how to manage Maven profiles with Spring profiles? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420745/how-to-set-spring-active-profiles-with-maven-profiles) question is the opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, it is not possible nor does it make sense. Maven is a build tool, and thus finished its work long before your Spring application even starts.

What's your use case why you want to do that? Maybe if we understand that, we can give you a more helpful answer.

Comment: The thing is that the those profiles in maven are needed to configure which directory in "resources" to use for generating java files from .wsdl files using org.apache.cxf-codegen-plugin. So in case the Spring profile is A, it tells Maven to look in A-profile's folder to generate. If it is B - the the B-profile's folder is used.

Comment: Thank you, I've truly been naive)) Figured that managing those profiles via spring is nonsense. So I should just pass them to mvn as an arguments

Comment: Glad you've figured out how to solve your problem!